# How to send data from a java application to elastic search without using the elasticsearch libraries

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I saw already answered questions and seems they are old enough that I couldn't use them. I tried an example given at https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-java-clients-for-elasticsearch which has the code written but not in an organized manner that would help me. The libraries are old and code gives me error.

I saw Spring Data project but that only allow a specific type of document/class to be indexed and needs the model to be predefined which is not my usecase. My goal is to build a java web application which could ingest any data documents fed to elasticsearch and we could analyze it with Kibana. I would need to know how can i fire a rest call or curl for bulk data. Can anyone state an example with complete parts please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [rest client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high.html).

> The Java High Level REST Client works on top of the Java Low Level
>   REST client. Its main goal is to expose API specific methods, that
>   accept request objects as an argument and return response objects, so
>   that request marshalling and response un-marshalling is handled by the
>   client itself.

To upload data from java application to ES , you can use [bulk Api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-bulk.html).

To check list of APIs check [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-supported-apis.html)

Comment: Well, I found that the solution in Java is very complex and time taking. I tried that and found myself in circles. Meanwhile, I found python useful for this scenario and example to that is shared here. https://tryolabs.com/blog/2015/02/17/python-elasticsearch-first-steps/